# Как отобразить компоненты при клике Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify

Понимаю,что вопрос довольно простой,но я только начинаю изучать Vue и почему-то не могу разобраться. У меня есть страница Login в которой должны появиться 2 компонента, если я кликну на кнопку Enter site.Как это сделать? Понимаю,что с помощью v-if,но не могу понять как что и кому передать. Вот код главной страницы,где должны появляться компоненты

```
<template>
  <v-container class="pa-0 ma-0" fluid>
    <v-row class="py-0 my-0">
      <v-col class="pa-0 ma-0"cols="12"><Preview /></v-col>
   
    </v-row>
    <v-row class="py-0 my-0" v-if="isOpen">
      <v-col class="pa-0 ma-0" sm="7" cols="12"><SignUp /></v-col>
      <v-col class="pa-0 ma-0" sm="5" cols="12"><SignIn /></v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import Preview from "@/components/Preview.vue";
import SignUp from "@/components/SignUp.vue";
import SignIn from "@/components/SignIn.vue";

export default {
  data: () => ({
    isOpen: false,
  }),
  components: { Preview, SignUp, SignIn },
};
</script>

А вот кнопка из компонента Preview,при клике на которую на странице Login должны появляться компоненты SignUp и SignIn

<template>
 <v-btn
            class="pa-5 mt-10 font-weight-light"
            outlined
            color="white"
            elevation="2"
            rounded
            x-large
           >
    Enter site
          </v-btn>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам необходимо использовать систему событий в Vue. На кнопку вешаете событие click с методом `onClick`, а в методе создаете событие, можете назвать его как угодно, в этом примере я назову его `previewButtonWasClicked` которое поднимется из компонента в родитель.

```
<button @click="onClick">
```

```
{
  methods: {
    onClick (e) {
      this.$emit("previewButtonWasClicked", e);
    }
  }
}
```

Теперь в родителе мы можем поймать событие `previewButtonWasClicked`, и повесить метод на это событие, который будет делать все что Вам нужно.

```
<v-col class="pa-0 ma-0"cols="12">
  <Preview @previewButtonWasClicked="yourMethod" />
</v-col>
```